# Cloning an Azure resource group using Deployment Details?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to replicate an existing Azure resource group using arm templates from the automation script section but running into a warning message about 10 resources types cannot be exported yet. One being Azure data factory. After searching online I found that templates for some resource types are not yet available. While looking at the Deployment section in my resource group, I am able to see a deployment details download link for each resource.

Can those be used to recreate each resource into a new resource group? Or is my best bet downloading the template from the automation script section and manually adding the resources for which the template are not yet available?

Any help would be appreciated.

Some of the warnings I got:

> ResourceTypeSchemaNotFound:
>
> ***The schema of resource type 'Microsoft.DataFactory/dataFactories' is not available. Resources of this type will not be exported to the
>   template. (Code: ResourceTypeSchemaNotFound, Target:
>   Microsoft.DataFactory/dataFactories
>
> ExportTemplateProviderError: all related to sql server
>
> ***Could not get resources of the type 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/connectionPolicies'. Resources of this type
>   will not be exported. (Code: ExportTemplateProviderError, Target:
>   Microsoft.Sql/servers/connectionPolicies)
>
> ***Could not get resources of the type 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/backupLongTermRetentionVaults'
>
> ***Could not get resources of the type 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/extendedAuditingSettings'.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure resource group ARM templates from the automation script section are not as comprehensive as they should probably be. For example, it is quite possible to deploy a Data Factory instance from ARM. It provides a reasonable starting point but you will find resources that don't deploy as well as a lot of superfluous cruft.

The approach I take is to start from a clean template in Visual Studio and then construct a project from a blank template or quick-start, then refer to the [template documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates) and build up from scratch, using your exported ARM template from your resource group to help work out how it should look. This results in a nice clean reusable template project.

Unfortunately I have not found an better way yet.

[image]